# Why is the client-server architecture of X-Window-System inverted?

Tags: xorg, architecture

I am total newbie in Linux and I have been reading about X Window System. The question that I have is:

- Why X-server is not running in the machine where the applications are
  really running and instead of this is running "inverted"? Why this
  was implemented "inverted"?

Answer (score 6):

The X server provides access to display, keyboard and mouse. To do that it needs to run on the machine where the display, keyboard and mouse are connected, just like e.g. a file server needs to run on the machine where the files are stored.

It's called the "server" because it is waiting for client programs to connect and use its services.

The clients may run somewhere else because they may need some hardware or software that is not available at the machine with the display.

When X was invented in the 1980s the applications had to run on the big mainframes because the user's terminal didn't have enough resources. Today the clients often run on a machine that is used as e.g. a file server and it may *feel* "inverted" because your machine is a client to that file server.

Comment: Thanks but could not I be implemented making the pc which doesnt have the applications running , doing requests to the server where the applications are running and the server would response with graphic data which the client could use to display? The same way, the client would send mouse or keyboard events and these would be processed by the server where the applications are running.